# toggle 1 line - complete line view + view one complete line in separate card

Tags: livecode

I'd like to toggle the display of the data grid between a 1-line view, complete line view with all the lines listed and a view of one complete line in a separate card.

The thing that has to be fixed is following:

Viewing of one complete/full line in a separate card when I click on the line row in 1-line view card (compacted), or on the line row in Complete line view card (expanded). I have used this code for the field "Line" in the Row Templates but it does not work properly:

```
 put fld "Line" into fld "fullLine" of cd "full_Line"  
 go to cd "full_Line"
```

Here is the link to the stack: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/Data%20grid%20Form-1%20line%20and%20complete%20line%20view%2Bopen%20Full%20line.zip

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Keram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In behaviors you always need to use "of me" to refer to the child controls. This is particularly important in a data grid where there's lots of groups with fields called Line

So try:

```
put fld "Line" of me into fld "fullLine" of cd "full_Line"
go cd "full_Line"
```

I just re-read and you said the script is on the line field itself so:

```
put the text of me into fld "fullLine" of cd "full_Line"
```